# Как динамически создавать колонки в javaFX и заполнять их?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

Есть исходный csv файл с данными. В зависимости от содержания файла нужно создать таблицу. Количество строк в таблице равно количеству строк в файле, количество столбцов соответственно равно количеству значений в одной строке.
Вот собственно код:

Класс InputDate.java

```
public class InputDate {

    private ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public InputDate(String[] items){
        this.items.addAll(Arrays.asList(items));
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getItems(){
        return items;
    }

}
```

Класс JavaFXKursovaya.java

```
public class JavaFXKursovaya extends Application {

    private TabPane root = new TabPane();
    private ObservableList<InputDate> os1 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private int rowsInpDate = 0;
    private int colsInpDate = 0;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

            //Create view
        Tab tab1 = new Tab("Загрузка БД");
        HBox navDB = new HBox(20.0);
        Button downloadDB = new Button("Загрузить БД"); 
        ComboBox listOfTables = new ComboBox();
        FlowPane content_tab1 = new FlowPane(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        TableView<InputDate> tableDB = new TableView();


        downloadDB.setOnAction((ae)-> {
            createContent_tab1(tableDB);
        });


        navDB.getChildren().addAll(downloadDB, listOfTables);
        content_tab1.getChildren().addAll(navDB, tableDB);
        tab1.setContent(content_tab1);

        root.getTabs().add(tab1);
            //settings for root
        root.setTabClosingPolicy(TabClosingPolicy.UNAVAILABLE);
            //Creating the scene
        primaryStage.setTitle("Система обработки входных данных");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 600));
        primaryStage.show();

    }

        //First tab controller
    public void createContent_tab1(TableView<InputDate> tableDB){

        tableDB.getColumns().clear();
        tableDB.getItems().clear();

        csvParser();

            //Fill the table
        for(int i = 0; i <= colsInpDate - 1; i++){
            TableColumn<InputDate, String> tableColumn = new TableColumn<>("" + i);
            tableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("items[" + i + "]"));
            tableDB.getColumns().add(tableColumn);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < os1.size(); i++)
            System.out.println("os1 index " + i + " = " + os1.get(i).getItems());

        tableDB.setItems(os1); 

        tableDB.setEditable(false);
        tableDB.setFixedCellSize(25.0);
    }

        //Parser for csv file
    public void csvParser(){

        String csvFile = "C://Users/Wixes/Desktop/Development/Software" +
                         "/JavaFXKursovaya/src/javafxkursovaya/csvFiles/text.csv";
        String line = "";
        String csvSplitBy = ",";

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile))){

            rowsInpDate = 0;
            colsInpDate = 0;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){

                rowsInpDate += 1;
                System.out.println("rows = " + rowsInpDate);

                String[] fields = line.split(csvSplitBy, -1);

                colsInpDate = fields.length;
                System.out.println("cols = " + colsInpDate);

                InputDate inpd = new InputDate(fields);
                System.out.println("input date model = " + inpd.getItems());

                os1.add(inpd);
            }
        } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

text.csv

```
0,1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10,11
12,13,14,15,16,17
```

Контроль измерений System.out.println выводит:

```
rows = 1
cols = 6
input date model = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
rows = 2
cols = 6
input date model = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
rows = 3
cols = 6
input date model = [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
os1 index 0 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
os1 index 1 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
os1 index 2 = [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
```

При нажатии на кнопку создаётся таблица с правильным количеством столбцов и строк (при нажатии на строках они выделяются, если в csv задано 3 строки, то и в таблице 3, если 5, то и в таблице 5 и т.д). Но данные в таблицу не выводятся, все ячейки пустые. Есть подозрение, что неправильно создал класс InputDate, но попытки его изменения не привели ни к какому результату. Что я сделал не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените блок:

```
//Fill the table
for(int i = 0; i <= colsInpDate - 1; i++){
    TableColumn<InputDate, String> tableColumn = new TableColumn<>("" + i);
    tableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("items[" + i + "]"));
    tableDB.getColumns().add(tableColumn);
}
```

на

```
//Fill the table
for(int i = 0; i <= colsInpDate - 1; i++){
    final int indexColumn = i;
    TableColumn<InputDate, String> tableColumn = new TableColumn<>("" + i);
    tableColumn.setCellValueFactory(param -> new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().getItems().get(indexColumn)));
    tableDB.getColumns().add(tableColumn);
}
```

Использование `PropertyValueFactory` в данном случае не уместно, т.к. у вас нет определенной модели данных с именованными полями.

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё работает!